# how to unselect jquery-select2 single

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I want a single select list with the option to unselect the value selected.

```
<label for="ticket_status" class="control-label">Ticket Status:</label>
                    <select class="js-basic-ticket-status">
                    </select>

ticket_status = [{"id":"Cancelled","text":"Cancelled"},{"id":"Closed","text":"Closed"},{"id":"Completed","text":"Completed"},{"id":"Draft","text":"Draft"},{"id":"Implementation In Progress","text":"Implementation In Progress"},{"id":"Planning In Progress","text":"Planning In Progress"},{"id":"Rejected","text":"Rejected"},{"id":"Request For Change","text":"Request For Change"},{"id":"Scheduled","text":"Scheduled"},{"id":"Scheduled For Approval","text":"Scheduled For Approval"},{"id":"Scheduled For Review","text":"Scheduled For Review"}];
$(".js-basic-ticket-status").select2({
                placeholder: "Select Status",
                /*initSelection: function(element, callback) {                   
                },*/
                allowClear: true,
                data: ticket_status,
                //multiple: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
            });
```

I can see the 'x' on the top right corner but nothing happens when clicked on.

Comment: Post some html too and will be glad to help if we had Demo.. :)

Comment: What's the `select2` version you are using?

Comment: **[Works well here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8udp7wmw/2/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Select2 4.0.2-rc.1

Comment: Check the demo in last comment.. The close works well with your `code`